# text-ellipsis on fluid button above a fluid container

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

I have a box, the size of which is defined by the img in it. in this image there is a button which can hold a text of arbitrary quantity. If the text is less than the image beihnd it, then the button is to be placed in the middle, and if the text is more than the image, then it has to be cut with text-ellipsis. The maximum size of the text must be the width of the image so it cannot go over the box even if it does not fit in. Does anybody know a solition for this ONLY using CSS? Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h3emzbcq/3/

```
<div class="border-box">
<div class="item-pic">
    <img src="http://demo7.firstvoicemedia.com/u5.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="item-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-green"><span class="btn-text">Text place Text place Text placeText place Text place Text place</span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Text place

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I see you jsfiddle just fine. I think i don't understand your question properly. Could you explain a little more the problem you're suffering?

Comment: If the text is short, it is in centered position, whereas if there is a lot of text and the image wouldn't fit vertically, the button lies horizontally all the way along the image/container, + the text is cut with text-ellipse. Do you understand me? :)

Comment: Actually, what you just said fits in the jsfiddle provided on you question. And I don't see the problem with your implementation. Now that I see the accepted answer I see that you want to fit the width of the button to the text until reached the width of the image but I don't see a reference for that needed on your question. Or I need glasses who knows!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width` and set `max-width: 100%` on the `<button>`:

```
.btn {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    /* added */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here is the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/h3emzbcq/8/).

Comment: text-ellipsis (...) is needed if the text longer than the button.